# Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies (flutter_absolute_path)

Tags: flutter, dart, absolute-path

Does the `flutter_absolute_path` v1.0.6 dependency not support null safety? Is there any other solution to get absolute path of a file?

```
for (int i = 0; i < resultList.length; i++) {
   var path = await 
   FlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath(resultList[i].identifier);
   print(path + '**path**');
   f.add(File(path));
}
```

Comment: Because `flutter_absolute_path` hasn't been migrated to null safety. Here is an already opened issue https://github.com/KasemJaffer/flutter_absolute_path/issues/11

Answer (score 2):

Try this plugin file_picker `file_picker: ^3.0.3`

```
//use this line to pick files
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();


//use this to process what file is returned
 if(result != null) {
   File file = File(result.files.single.path);
} else {
   // User canceled the picker
}
```

You can read about extra features here:
https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker